# Work to out a condition for my program

Tags: php

I need a little help with a program/script I am making for a slot style game, the idea is there will be 3 numbers randomly generated and each will correspond to a prize you can win, there will be a limited number of prizes and so each code (which will be sent out as the prize) will have to be checked to make sure it is in stock, if it is not in stock it will not be added to the draw.

So far I have my script checking if a code is in stock and if it is it adds the number to an array which I will then check through a switch and case

But I am not sure how to setup the switch and case, I thought about adding a set number to the 'pot' which will then be used with the 3 randomly generated numbers

```
$number1 = rand(0,$pot);
```

But doing it this way I would have to setup a statement whereby I would check each number and if it was in a certain range ie

```
if (($number1 > 150) && ($number1 < 349)){
// You win this prize
}
else if (($number 1 > 350) && ($number1 < 499)){
// You win this prize
}
else {
//You win this prize
}
```

But obviously this method would only work if all codes were in stock because if they weren't I would be giving out prizes I don't have

```
function generate_numbers(){
global $numbers;
$numbers = array(
    '0' => rand(1,4),
    '1' => rand(1,4),
    '2' => rand(1,4)
);
display_numbers();
}
```

This generates the numbers currently but works on just 4 variables so code a = the value of 1 code b = value of 2 etc

```
//SETUP VARIABLES
$num1; $num2; $num3;
//SET VARIABLE VALUES
function setup_variables(){
global $num1, $num2, $num3, $numbers;
    $num1 = $numbers[0];
    $num2 = $numbers[1];
    $num3 = $numbers[2];
    result();
}
```

This converts the array into single variables, it might not be the suggested method but I can change it if needs be

```
function result(){
global $num1, $num2, $num3;
    if ($num1 == $num2 && $num1 == $num3){
        if ($num1 == 1){
            $_SESSION['prize'] = 1;
            header("Location: win.php");
        }
        else if ($num1 == 2){
            $_SESSION['prize'] = 2;
            header("Location: win.php");
        }
        else if ($num1 == 3){
            $_SESSION['prize'] = 3;
            header("Location: win.php");
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['prize'] = 0;
        }
    }

    else{
        $_SESSION['prize'] = 0;
    }
}
```

This checks if the numbers match, if they do then it checks which number $num1 was and relays that to a prize that can be won using `$_SESSION['prize']`

But as you can see it works on single numbers I would rather it work on a range of numbers so I can add variation and chance to the game, with certain prizes appearing more often than others

On the next page it simply queries the database based on the data given through $_SESSION['prize'] which is equal to a ItemID in the database and shows the code on screen + email it to the winner

TLDR :

Basically I want a way to display a written code based upon if the code is Available (Boolean database value) I do not want to display codes that are not Available and so they should be excluded from the script entirely and each code should have a different chance of winning, more valuable codes having a lower chance of appearing, less valuable codes having a higher chance.

Basically this is a php version of Slots but slots based on current stock

Comment: Sounds like you need a database of prize codes, so you can mark them as already given away? This could have a 'from' and 'to' and be marked with 'is_won' as true when it is won, so that you don't consider "winning" codes in that range after it is no longer available.

Comment: I already have a database setup with a boolean available - 1 means they are unused, 0 means they are used, but I need a way to calculate what prize will be given out. So for example if I have code x code y and code z in stock but I do not have code a or code b. I need it to calculate given the above variables, which codes can be given out and more importantly which codes cannot be given out I will edit my original post to show what I currently have setup

Comment: Hmm, this is quite a big question. I'd start off with changing `result()` to not contain any hardwiring - the prize names, codes and images should be in a database, with this function looping over a record subset to determine what (if anything) has been won.

Comment: I'd then move onto databasifying your `if` section (with the "You win this prize" comments) that takes available prizes into account. I might be inclined to recommend working on that, and then asking a new question _with your database structure_. As it stands, I think this question might be quite a localised one!

Comment: I think you might be right this is quite a localised question, but I have done as you suggested the if statement now only contains `$_SESSION['prize'] = 1;` and a header to link to the 'win' page, I am now trying to think up a way to sort through the available codes and use the available ones in an algorithm 
I have `$stock = $conn -> query('SELECT DISTINCT ItemID FROM codes WHERE Available = 1');`
which selects the ItemIDs which are available, I need to work on a way to use this data to select a prize

Comment: You could fetch the results as a numbered array, then use your random number generator to 'choose' an index, then use the item that lies at that index in your results. For instance if that query returns: `0->Item1; 1->Item3; 2->Item8`, you could produce a random number between 0 and 2, and use that as the index for the prize you choose.

Comment: That is similar to how I have it setup currently, 3 numbers are generated at random and they correspond to a prize that can be won, the problem is that not all prizes should have an equal chance of winning, for example `Code A has a 25% chance of being won, Code B has a 30% chance and Code C only has a 0.5% chance` so my issue is finding an effective way of sorting the data by chance to win, which will be reliant on whether or not the code is active or not. The prize will be given by successfully matching 3 numbers/prizes, like a slot machine